# getServerSideProps timed out function in production, vercel consuming express api and mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, next.js, vercel

This question is more about how Vercel serverless functions work. I have requested an express.js with MongoDB and taking around 0.078 seconds to at most 1.856 seconds.

`getServerSideProps` works perfect on LocalHost. However, whenever I use the `getServerSideProps`, I get the error

```
[GET] /articles/637a08a20218e2e3c841e8d7
22:58:07:13
2022-11-20T20:58:17.290Z 881d4090-532d-42df-9ee2-dd759a6eae08 Task timed out after 10.02 seconds
```

Of course, `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` works perfectly but I'll be having around 100000 dynamic routes to create which isn't scalable. I'm already using `SWR` for index pages (list of articles with pagination) but I can't use it for dynamic pages because it's bad for SEO

My question is, what's the cause of this timeout?

API: Express hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, MongoDB Atlas serverless
Next.js

```js
// [articleID].tsx
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { article } = context.params;
  const article = await getFetcher(`/articles/${articleID}`);

  if (!article) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: { article },
  };
};
```

Reusable fetch

```js
async function getFetcher(path: string) {
  if (!path) return;

  const url = `${API_BASE_URL}${path}`;

  // headers
  const headers = {
    Authorization: AUTHORIZED_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  };

  const config = { headers };

  const response = await axios
    .get(url, config)
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("GET Resource Error");
      console.log(error);
      return { success: false, error, message: error.message };
    });

  return response;
}
```